# Sharepoint Contribute permission issue

Tags: c#, sharepoint

I have a sharepoint webpart in which a textbox and submit button will be given.  Click the submit button should create a set of folders and subfolders and assign permission to a Group which have contribute permission.

Everything works fine, instead even if the user/Group contribute permission, they can not upload file to the document library.

I used the following set of code to add permission to folder/subfolders dynamically.

```
   SPGroup oGroup = web.Groups.GetByID (oFieldUserValue.LookupId);                                        
   SPPrincipal principal = (SPPrincipal)oGroup;
   SPRoleAssignment roleAssignment = new SPRoleAssignment(principal);                                        
   permFolder.Item.BreakRoleInheritance(true);                                        
   roleAssignment.RoleDefinitionBindings.Add(web.RoleDefinitions["Contribute"]);
   permFolder.Item.RoleAssignments.Add(roleAssignment);
   permFolder.Item.Update();
   finalItem.Update();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using the SPRoleAssignment object, e.g.

// Assuming you already have SPWeb and SPList objects
...

```
SPRoleDefinition roleDefinition = web.RoleDefinitions.GetByType(SPRoleType.Contributor);
roleAssignment.RoleDefinitionBindings.Add(roleDefinition);
if (!myList.HasUniqueRoleAssignments)
{
    myList.BreakRoleInheritance(true); // Ensure we don't inherit permissions from parent
} 
myList.RoleAssignments.Add(roleAssignment);
myList.Update();
```

Answer (score 0):

have you checked uploading documents from ribbin menu if Add New Item option is appearing. for all the users having contribute permission for that particular folder.